# What is wrong about this SQL statement?

Tags: php, sql

Here is the containing PHP file:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../includes/dbcxnfunction.inc");

$billid = $_POST['billid'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$query = "IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM favoritebills WHERE userid = '$userid' AND billid = '$billid' )
              DELETE FROM favoritebills WHERE userid = '$userid' and billid = '$billid'         
          ELSE
              INSERT INTO favoritebills (userid,billid) VALUES($userid,$billid) ";

$result = mysqli_query(dbcxn('bill'),$query)
              or exit("Couldn't execute query for favorites");

if($result)
    {
    $request = "true";
    }
else 
    {
        $request = "false";
    }

echo $request;

?>
```

The query is:

```
"IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM favoritebills WHERE userid = '$userid' AND billid = '$billid' )
          DELETE FROM favoritebills WHERE userid = '$userid' and billid = '$billid'         
      ELSE
          INSERT INTO favoritebills (userid,billid) VALUES($userid,$billid) ";
```

userid and billid are both integers.

This is my network tab:

[image]

In my .js file I have `console.log(response);`

The console is logging "Couldn't execute query for favorites"

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: That's not a query, it's a statement. It can only be used as part of a stored procedure.

Comment: Come on!  You mention no error message, no unexpected behaviour, nothing.  Are we meant to be psychic?

Comment: The only error message I am getting is the one I designed into the mysqli_query()'s "or exit()"  The only unexpected behavior is that the query isn't working.

Comment: You're not getting a detailed error message because you never call `mysqli_error()` to see the reason for the failure.

Comment: Okay, I will add it.  Would this go just after the mysqli_query()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `IF` as a statement in a query, it can only be used in a stored procedure. To do what you want, you need two separate queries. Try this:

```
$del_query = "DELETE FROM favoritebills WHERE userid = '$userid' and billid = '$billid'";
$ins_query = "INSERT INTO favoritebills (userid,billid) VALUES($userid,$billid) ";

$res = mysqli_query(dbcxn('bill'),$del_query)
  or die ("Couldn't execute DELETE query: " . dbxcn('bill')->error);
if (dbcxn('bill')->affected_rows == 0) { // The row didn't exist, so add it
  $res = mysqli_query(dbcxn('bill'),$ins_query)
    or die ("Couldn't execute INSERT query: " . dbxcn('bill')->error);
}

$result = "true"; // No need to test for false, since we die above in that case
```

Comment: It is probably better to use prepared statements

Comment: Yes, I just didn't feel like doing that much rewriting.

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/unipartisan/ajaxphp/favorites.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
true

Comment: So it is returning true, and the query is executing, it just seems to not like $res->num_rows for some reason.

Comment: Fixed it. The property is on the connection, not the result.

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: mysqli::$num_rows in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/unipartisan/ajaxphp/favorites.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />  Is what it returns now.  Still also returns true.

Comment: I just checked the documentation, and my first version was correct. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem. It only returns a mysqli_result for SELECT queries, not DELETE.

Comment: For DELETE, it's `dbcxn('bill')->affected_rows`

Comment: There are no more errors in the console, but the database is not reflecting any changes, and the image that should be toggling are not doing so.  I will just have to look into this some more later, but you have solved the issue with my SQL statement, and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The problems were with the php and the AJAX response.  I did a query of "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favoritebills where userid = $userid AND billid = $billid" then I did an if($result['COUNT(*)'] == 1{"DELETE FROM favoritebills..."} else {"INSERT INTO..."}  the affected rows object was not working for some reason, but the problem is solved 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that if the records exist, you eliminate them, leaving nothing?
The insert only happens if the records do not exist.

do not try to combine them, 
run 2 queries, 
    Delete from where
      then
    Insert